# Using regex to extract a string

Tags: regex, string, replace, google-apps-script, indexof

I am using Google Apps Script to return a text string from simple comments entity in a database into Google Sheets.  I would like to identify certain comments that contain my own 'bbCode' such as [Status: Complete].  But I am not sure how to extract the 'Complete' text and how to remove the entire '[Status: Complete]' bbCode from the comment text.  This is where I have got to so far - thank you for any suggestions:

Example 1 comment text: '[Status: Complete] Lorem ipsum bla bla'
Desired output:      Col1: 'Lorem ipsum bla bla'      Col2: 'Complete'

Example 2 comment text: 'Lorem [Status: Proposed] ipsum bla bla'
Desired output:      Col1: 'Lorem ipsum bla bla'      Col2: 'Proposed'

Example 3 comment text: 'Lorem ipsum bla bla'
Desired output:      Col1: 'Lorem ipsum bla bla'     Col2:

```
var bbCode = '[Status: ";
//get data from db and for next into val
  var val = rs.getString(col+1);
  if (val.indexOf(bbCode) > -1) {
// Item with Status, place the status in the Status Column 
//but this next line is not right - I would like var Status = 'Complete' or 'Proposed' etc...
  var Status = RegExp(.*\[Status: (.*)\].*', 'g');
  cell.offset(row, col+2).setValue(Status);
// Place the remaining comment in the Comment column
//This next line is not right I would like val = the comment string without the '[Status: Completed]' or '[Status: Proposed]' etc...
  cell.offset(row, col+2).setValue(val);
} else {
// Enter comment in Comment column as normal
  cell.offset(row, col+1).setValue(val);
}
```

Comment: Are the `<br/>` and `nbsp;` part of the actual comment text, or is that for formatting?

Comment: Hi Laurel, the input comment string may well include some html, but in this case I think the examples just have some odd formatting - I was just trying to line up the two columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample:

```
function RegexGetTwoStrings() {

Logger.log('^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^');
var sample = ['[Status: Complete] Lorem ipsum bla bla',
              'Lorem [Status: Proposed] ipsum bla bla',
              'Lorem ipsum bla bla'];


var RegEx = /(.*)\[.*: (.*)\] (.*)/;
var Replace = "$1$3,$2";


var str, newStr, Col1, Col2;
var strArr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < sample.length; i++) {
      str = sample[i];
      newStr = str.replace(RegEx, Replace) + ",";
      strArr = newStr.split(',');

      Col1 = strArr[0];
      Col2 = strArr[1];

      Logger.log("Sample1 = '" + str + "'");
      Logger.log('Col1 = ' + Col1);
      Logger.log('Col2 = ' + Col2);

  }

Logger.log('^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^');

}
```